# Using Writable stream as an event emitter

Tags: node.js, pipe, jsonstream

I am wondering if it is possible to use a writable stream (`require('stream').Writable`) as an event emitter.

For example,

```
   var jsonData = [];

   var strm = new stream.Writable({
        write: function(chunk, encoding, next) {

            jsonData.push(chunk.toString());
            next();
        }

    });


    strm.on('foo',function(msg){
        console.log(msg); //doesn't get called
    });

    strm.emit('foo','bar');  //this doesn't seem to do anything
```

I thought that Readable/Writable streams were event-emitters, but it doesn't seem I can really use them this way? Also wondering if I am using Writable correctly by writing to an array outside of the Writable object/stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams indeed event-emitters, your code sample works perfectly fine on node `v4.2.4`

```
vladmiller:tmp vladmiller$ node test.js
bar
```

and node `v0.12.7`

```
vladmiller:tmp vladmiller$ node test.js
bar
```

Comment: yeah one thing I was wondering if events can still be emitted if the stream is closed / finished / end event has been called etc.

Comment: @AlexMills most likely it will always emit events just because streams inherit EventEmitter, but I'd rather make an experiment to be sure

Comment: yeah it seems to work, I can use emit/on after finish/end